# Matlab Discrete cosine transform algorithm giving me wrong coefficients

Tags: algorithm, matlab, dct

Im trying to use the two dimensional DCT for an .ppm Image with the size of 256. Here is the formula that used for my script.

[image]

The Problem is when im comparing my coefficient with the coefficient of the 
official dct2 matlab function they are all different. But somehow im still being able to use the inverse formula and getting the exact same image back. How is this possible with wrong coefficients and what should i change to get the correct coefficients?

```
sum = 0;
for x=1:32
  for y=1:32
    for u=1:8
      for v=1:8
        if(u ~= 0 && v ~= 0)
          T(x,y,u,v) = (1/4)*1/sqrt(2)*1/sqrt(2)*cos(((2*x+1)*pi*u)/16)*cos(((2*y+1)*pi*v)/16);
        else
          T(x,y,u,v) = (1/4)*1*1*cos(((2*x+1)*pi*u)/16)*cos(((2*y+1)*pi*v)/16);
        end
        DCTT(u,v) = A(x*u,y*v)*T(x,y,u,v);
        disp(DCTT(u,v));
      end
    end
  end
end

save dct.num DCTT;
fid = fopen('dct.num');
D = textscan(fid,'%f', 'delimiter', ',');
fclose(fid);
disp(D);

sum=0;
for x=1:32
  for y=1:32
    for u=1:8
      for v=1:8
        A(x*u,y*v) = A(x*u,y*v) + (DCTT(u,v)*T(x,y,u,v));
      end
    end
  end
end

imwrite (A, 'imageAfter.ppm')

imshow(A);
```

Comment: `for (u=1:8), for (v=1:8), if(u ~= 0 && v ~= 0)` <== It seem you have a problem there, as u and v never take the value 0. It may be an indexing issue (i.e. the values of `u` & `v` corresponding to the first sample of the output DCTT(1,1) may not be 1 and 1). Perhaps something like `for u=0:7, for v=0:7,` *(...)* `DCCT(u+1,v+1)=A...` ?

Comment: In you first very imbricated loop, what is the point of the test  " if(u ~= 0 && v ~= 0)" because $u>0$ and $v>0$ ?